# How to pass tensor to model.predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have defined a function as follows where generator and discriminator are both two Keras models.

```
def build_combined():
    # The generator takes noise as input and generates imgs
    z = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    img = generator(z)

    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    discriminator.trainable = False

    # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
    validity = discriminator(img)

    # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
    # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
    combined = Model(z, validity)
    combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer)
    return combined
```

How I can write down the same functionally of above function with the following:

```
def build_combined():
    # The generator takes noise as input and generates imgs
    z = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    img = generator(z)

    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    # The discriminator takes generated images as input and determines validity
    validity = discriminator.predict(K.eval(img))


    # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
    # Trains the generator to fool the discriminator
     combined = Model(z, validity)
     combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer)
     return combined
```

Comment: You can specify the shape of the tensor fully. If you provide more information it might clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you need the second code segment? The first should work fine.

Comment: I know the first implementation is correct. I want to expand my knowledge for other possible solution. We can see, the Discriminator model is only on its inference mode, why not use model.predict